# Python - Fastest / Best way to apply a function to each element of a numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am wondering what is the fastest (or "best" due to some reason) method to apply a function to each element of a numpy array. I tried this method with a larger data set and it takes quite a while... Post your answer with the results (time in milliseconds) you got on my implementation and yours,as different HW will give different results on the same code

Please share your implementation between the 2 commented lines

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Some random data
x = np.random.rand(5,32,32,3)*255
x = x.astype(int)

# Defining some function
def normalize(x, a=0, b=1, x_min=0, x_max=255):
    return a + (x - x_min)*(b - a)/(x_max-x_min)

## Start timer
start_time = time.time()

# ---------------------IMPLEMENTATION---------------------
# Apply Normalize function to each element in the array
n = np.vectorize(normalize)
x = n(x)
#_________________________________________________________

# Stop timer and show time in milliseconds
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("Time [ms] = " + str(elapsed_time*1000))
```

Comment: Just do all operations on the whole array, not using vectorize! (like x += 1)

Comment: Can you post what you mean as an answer?

Comment: Someone eventually will. But to be honest: did you spend 5 mins with the docs? Your function is very suitable to exploit numpy's vectorized operations. No loops needed. The docs also warn about np.vectorize (somewhat a hidden loop)! The solution is more or less the same code, just doing the operations on the array x itself. No wrapping.

Comment: As @sascha mentioned, if each elementwise operation is independent and f(M(m, n)) = N(m, n), i.e. input and output are the same shape arrays, then simply apply the function the entire array. Some trivial examples are, for array A, `np.abs(A)`, `A**2`, `A - 5`, `2*A`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried re-inventing the wheel :) I will try spending time with docu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @sascha , I just need to apply the function to the whole array:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Some random data
x = np.random.rand(5,32,32,3)*255
x = x.astype(int)

# Defining some function
def normalize(x, a=0, b=1, x_min=0, x_max=255):
    return a + (x - x_min)*(b - a)/(x_max-x_min)

## Start timer
start_time = time.time()

# ---------------------IMPLEMENTATION---------------------
# Apply Normalize function to each element in the array
x = normalize(x)
#_________________________________________________________

# Stop timer and show time in milliseconds
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("Time [ms] = " + str(elapsed_time*1000))
```